# Brain and UV rays

Tags: biophysics

I heard that brain can be switched off using ultra violet rays. I seek experts comments on this. Is it true? If it is so how it is possible to control brain by UV rays?

Comment: you can fry (well, really damage) a brain using UV, but I never heard that you can excite or inhibit it using UV light. Where did you hear that?

Comment: http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/could-certain-frequencies/ . effects discussed are with low frequency and magnetic fields. http://io9.com/5851828/10-things-an-electromagnetic-field-can-do-to-your-brain also

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about brain physiology not physics

Comment: Please consider for migration to Biology stack exchange

Answer (score 1):

UV rays are absorbed by skin and bone.  In order to expose the brain to UV rays, you would have to remove it from the skull, which would have the totally irrelevant side effect of interfering with the brain's functioning.

Comment: My comment of course assumed an open skull, and I was thinking of macaques. I do not know if you have any idea of the kind of creepy research some neuroscientists they perform on them.

Answer (score 1):

I think the OP is referring to either [optogenetics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optogenetics) or the fact that the skull is transparent to [IR light and can affect chemical processes in the brain](http://www.medpagetoday.com/Neurology/GeneralNeurology/43985).